# How to reduce the server initial waiting time?

Tags: php, jquery, apache, xampp

I'm using ubuntu apache and my site is created from php, jquery and necessary html & css.

Already I have done lot of things for improve performance. All the js calls after css and first fold no js & css blocking and  minimizing css js and sprite images everything is already done.

Now my need is I have to reduce the server initial response time. and

Also sprite image is taking 1 sec to load for just 90kb file.

Can anyone help me to fix these issues.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some great tips about improving  site speed

[`http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html`](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html)

in your case, you need to flush the buffer early, here's a detailed explanations:
[`http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#flush`](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#flush)
and of course profile your code and see if you can improve anything there.

you could also make use of Yslow [`http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/`](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/)

for sprite to load faster, see if you can compress more then you already probably did,
try to remove something if you can to make it smaller, use a cdn for it.